# Wordpress admin gives me 500 error

Tags: php, wordpress

I am hosting a site locally via MAMP, but somehow while editing sidebar (tried to edit widgets), site went blank and it cannot give me access to wordpress admin panel. It shows up 500 error and blank page.
Site has multiple themes assigned to different pages, so when I try to access homepage (arcade basic theme) it works fine. But when I try to access Shop (mystile theme), it shows blank page and 500 error. 
The 500 error is also received when I try to access admin panel via wordpress dashboard (on my homepage).
what can I do?

Comment: have you added any plugin ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case you didn't know, 500 errors mean there's a server misconfiguration somewhere.

This could easily be down to an error in coding, which clearly this sounds like.

You would be helped greatly by looking in your apache error logs (usually in your log folders), this should tell you what caused the error - or you could also try turning PHP error display on, which may display the same information but on the screen.

Once you find out where abouts in the code the error is being generated, update your answer, along with an excerpt of that area of the code, and others may be able to help you better.

Another suggestion would be to try using an IDE software application to write your code, as this will flag up any errors as you type them. Personally, I use [NetBeans](http://www.netbeans.org).